# Создание приложения для блокировки телефона Python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

Всем привет, у меня возник вопрос. Как получать номер телефона человека, который тебе звонит и блокировать его? Вопрос в том, что мне использовать для этого (какие библиотеки и тд). Пример мне звонит рекламная компания и этот номер есть у меня в базе (программа его сразу блокирует). Хочу разработать на python под android.

Comment: не трать время зря, а поставь любое из уже имеющихся приложений

Comment: Сама идея создать самому!

Comment: для "идея создать самому" обычно берут те проекты, которые под силу, а не те, где совершенно ничего не знаешь, и которые выглядят как "хочу повесить на стену картину с помощью картофелечистки".

Comment: Разве брать проекты, которые не под силу это плохо? В любом случае надо развиваться. Я не прошу написать ее за меня, просто хочу получить направление и стараться реализовать это, а не сидеть с пустыми руками и ждать когда кто-то реализует это вместо меня, до этого надо дойти самому.

Comment: Да, плохо. А чтобы развиваться, нужно понимать что делать и зачем. И самое главное - уметь выбирать для задачи подходящие инструменты. А сейчас вы собираетесь весить картину с помощью картофелечистки. Можно, наверное, извратиться, но лучше взять молоток и гвоздь. "_ждать когда кто-то реализует это вместо меня_" - уже не надо ждать, потому что реализовали.

Comment: Ну, я думаю, вполне можно писать какой-то проект, в котором ты мало чего понимаешь чтобы разобраться и ⇒ развиться. Только на мой взгляд нужно сразу брать соответсвующие технологии, а не пробовать, на том, что уже хорошо знаешь, но вообще не подходит. Т.е. рекомендую раз андроид — то джава.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904426/how-to-block-a-mobile-number-call-and-message-receiving-in-android-application-d)

Comment: Начиная с Android 7 есть [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService). Это API позволяет блокировать входящие звонки до того, как пользователь их увидит.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше стремление к разработке приложений - это хорошо, но python не совсем заточен под android разработку. Лучше всего работает C++/Java/C#/Kotlin. Но если вы понимаете синтаксис и у вас есть опыт работы с этим ЯП, то добро пожаловать в *kivy*!